# Populating Custom ListView in a Fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-activity, android-tablayout

I have two activities, the main activity invokes a navigation drawer and one of the drawer items invokes another activity(event_activity) containing a Swipeable Tabbed layout. Each tab is a fragment invoked by the the event_activity. Now i want to populate custom ListViews to each fragment from a json data.
I tried using [THIS](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/) tutorial, but its meant to be used with an activity, so got error while doing it with my fragment.
So, is there any way to populate the fragments using custom listviews?

[Tabbed layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfw1c.jpg)

This is my event_activity

```
package com.explore.sargam.activity;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.explore.sargam.R;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.explore.sargam.OneFragment;
import com.explore.sargam.ThreeFragment;
import com.explore.sargam.TwoFragment;
import com.explore.sargam.FourFragment;


public class ResultActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private Toolbar toolbar;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);



    }




    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "Day 1");
        adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "Day 2");
        adapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment(),"Day 3");
        adapter.addFragment(new FourFragment(), "Day 4");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_result, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my Fragment code

```
package com.explore.sargam;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class TwoFragment extends Fragment{


    private static final String TAG = TwoFragment.class.getSimpleName();


    public TwoFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);


    }


}
```

Comment: Please post the error, line and exception

Comment: "so got error while doing it with my fragment", what is the error message that you have specifically?

Comment: What you want exactly?